# How to detect if Authorisation Status changed when application is opened from Settings

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, user-permissions

I am showing a pop up when user denies to the location permission. That pop has a button to take the user to the settings. When the user goes to the settings and allows the permission and then comes back to the application; How can I refresh my view?

[image]

Comment: use notification center

Comment: NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(applicationDidBecomeActiveNotification(notification:)), name: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)

Comment: Thanks @SPatel for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recheck location permission in `applicationWillEnterForeground` in **appDelegate.swift** file and send notification to your view controller using notification observer

**yourViewcontroller.swift**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(updateLocationPermission(notfication:)), name: "updateLocation", object: nil)
}

@objc func updateLocationPermission(notfication: NSNotification) {
     print("location updated")
}
```

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        let nc = NotificationCenter.default
        nc.post(name: Notification.Name("updateLocation"), object: nil)        
}
```

Comment: I don't think it work, because he/she want did enter foreground event

Comment: @SPatel when he/she come back from setting to application at that time call applicationWillEnterForeground

Comment: When user come back to app then call "applicationWillEnterForeground" and "applicationDidBecomeActive", But first method call "applicationWillEnterForeground" that's why written code in this method

Comment: No need to fire custom notification from `appDelegate` iOS has built in event `UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification`

Answer (score 1):

When you come back to the application, you should check the location permission status to update the change:

In `applicationDidBecomeActive` in `appDelegate.swift`, check `CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()`

Comment: Use `func sceneDidBecomeActive(_ scene: UIScene)` inside SceneDelegate for newer versions of iOS